# bash autocompletion with file names

Tags: bash, autocomplete, bash-completion

I can't get a simple bash autocompletion function to work. I need to autocomplete file names from a predefined directory so it will look like this:

```
$ cmd log<TAB><TAB>
file1.log file2.log file3.log
```

Where files are from `/var/log/app`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found this to work as needed:

```
COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "$(ls /var/log/app/)" -- $cur) )
```

Thanks to dogbane in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/28283/autocomplete-of-filename-in-directory !

Comment: This solution as written here did not work for me, but the solution in the linked question did. It is just a matter of properly setting `$cur`.

Answer (score 3):

I don't see the point of using `ls` when the shell can list files just fine by itself, so here's one using just the shell.

```
_cmd() {
    local files=("/var/log/app/$2"*)
    [[ -e ${files[0]} ]] && COMPREPLY=( "${files[@]##*/}" )
}
complete -F _cmd cmd
```

Comment: Impressive (but inscrutable for the novice) shell coding! The creation and use of `files` as an array is powerful. Arrays are documented at https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays

Answer (score -1):

Put them into `~/.bashrc`

```
_cmd() { COMPREPLY=($(ls /var/log/app)); }    
complete -F _cmd cmd
```

To write a full-featured auto-complete function,
please take a look at `/etc/bash_completion.d/python`.

Comment: `ls` is not necessary and it's not intended to be used that way. `_cmd() { COMPREPLY=(/var/log/app/*); }`

Comment: It does show the list of files in /var/log/app but when I type a letter to narrow the completion choices and then TAB the letter is being deleted and the completion returns to the original file list. See http://i.imgur.com/9TPMs.gif