# Bash filename autocompletion after switch/parameter

Tags: bash, autocomplete, filenames

I tried [this other questions's accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11490524/1598390) but it doesn't work for me. So please don't vote this as duplicate.

My script is named "tracker" and it accepts the following switches: `--dummy --audit_sessiones --user_count --detailed_user_count --parfile`

The `--parfile` switcj should be followed by a filename.

I have this autocompletion script:

```
_tracker() 
{
    local cur prev opts
    COMPREPLY=()
    cur="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD]}"
    prev="${COMP_WORDS[COMP_CWORD-1]}"
    opts="--dummy --audit_sessiones --user_count --detailed_user_count --parfile"

    if [[ ${cur} == -* ]] ; then
        COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -W "${opts}" -- ${cur}) )
        return 0
    fi

    opts="ls *"
    if [[ ${prev} == --parfile ]]; then 
        COMPREPLY=( "${files[@]##*/}" )
        return 0
    fi
}
complete -F _tracker tracker
```

Autocompletion of switches works fine.

But I also want the user to be able to use filename autocompletion right after the parameter `--parfile` but I haven't been able to make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`complete` has a `-o default` option so you can remove the `opts="ls *"; if ... fi` part and just do `complete -F _tracker -o default tracker`.

According to bash manual:

> If the `-o default` option  was supplied  to `complete` when
>   the compspec was defined, readline's default completion will
>   be performed if the compspec (and, if attempted, the default
>   bash completions) generate no matches.

Answer (score 1):

Try replacing `COMPREPLY=( "${files[@]##*/}" )` with `COMPREPLY=( $(compgen -f ${cur}) )`

More information about auto completion can be found in the following links

[An introduction to bash completion: part 1](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/316/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_1)

[An introduction to bash completion: part 2](http://www.debian-administration.org/article/317/An_introduction_to_bash_completion_part_2)